# How publish a windows phone 8.1 using cordova 7.x and Visual Studio 2017 Comunity

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

We have a developer acount and We published applications for windows phone 8.1 in the Window Store.
We used visual studio 2013 and Cordova 3.7.0. over windows 8.1
Our Apps could be opened in real windows phone 8 devices conected vía USB to PC.

Today We need update App in the store and We have installed windows 10 and Visual studio 2017 Comunity.

Visual studio shows errors with original cordova folder project so We updated nodejs and cordova to latest version. Cordova now is 7.0.1 version.

We add wp8 platform : cordova platform add wp8
But get error no
Error: Failed to fetch platform wp8
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.

It seems that wp8 platform no longer exists, right?

So We added windows platform : cordova platform add windows
This time cordova install platform windows 5.0.0

With this platform, We can open the solution in Visual studio 2017 and even We can launch it in Windows emulator very well.

but We cannot launch it in windows phone 8 emulator.
But We cannot launch it in a windows phone 8 real device conected vía USB to PC.

error in windows phone emulator is:

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error     DEP0001: Error inesperado: SmartDeviceException - El dato
>   necesario para completar esta operación no está disponible todavía.
>   [0x80131500]  CordovaApp.Windows10

Visual studio 2017 is logged in our developer account correctly.

We have been searching a lot but still do not get clear about how Msoft and cordova face the creation and publishing on windows phone 8 or 8.1.

Is this still possible? , Is there a new platform for mobile devices in microsoft?, Is it enough to use the windows platform in cordova to be able to publish to devices and test on windows phone devices?

Sorry our english and sorry if We have not explained ourselves well in something that makes the question unclear.

Let us get any questions about our question or further clarification at some point as the idea is to cooperate to help others pass.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install the windows 8.1 sdk for visual studio 2017?  You find it if you run the vs 2017 installer under individual components.  You will need to developer unlock the wp 8.1 device to debug you app on it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Summarizing a little, is it possible publish or run in device a cordova  windows app for phone  using visual studio 2017, cordova 7 on window 10. What do We need install for this? What platform in cordova must be added? I'm lost in very msoft docs and versiosn of visual studio and emulators.

Comment: Thanks ken, 
I'm going to follow your advice to see that I get, I needed a way to go, I was totally frozen

Comment: I installed windows 8.1 sdk in visual studio 2017. Anybody knows wich platform must be added to te cordova proyect.  It seem cordova platform add wp8 or cordova platform add wp   does not exist. But cordova platform add windows added OK. Can I compile and publish using only windows platform in cordova?

Comment: Msoft says  the Cordova tools in VS 2017 does not support Windows 8.1 development  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15320/windows-phone-81-not-supported.html

Comment: Still stuck in this. I have installed and installed windows phone 8.1 in visual studio 2017 comunity but I still do not recognize the project that previously opened and executed correctly in visual studio 2013 with windows phone 8.1 sdk  
But here Msoft himself says that VS 2017 no longer supports WP8.1 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs Down on that page they talk about this and I'm super bundled. Is it free VS 2015? Can I download a Comunity-type version?

Comment: If I finally decide to use VS 2017 and compile and publish the application as Universal (UWP App). After publishing it in Windows Store, could it be downloaded by Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 devices and executed? Or should I understand that Msoft already disregards WPhone 8 and 8.1 devices